# MySql is not accepting Unique constraint while having Auto Increment for another column

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE UserDetails (
    sno INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    location VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    country VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY(username)
);
```

It is giving the following error:

> ERROR 1075 (42000): Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

I want to set `sno` to auto increment and `username` to `UNIQUE` AND `NOT NULL`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is as the error message says: the `sno` column must also be defined as a key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sno` needs to be a `PRIMARY KEY` if you want it to be auto incremented. Replace:

```
sno INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

with

```
sno INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
```

Answer (score 0):

`sno` must be defined as a primary key (e.g. unique key) for auto_increment to work:

```
CREATE TABLE UserDetails (
    sno INT unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    etc...
)
```